# How to create a DAX function that will re-calculate when the referencing table is filtered

Tags: dax, powerquery

I have created a pivot table which contains measures that calculates values from another pivot table. Everything works correctly, however when I apply a filter to the referencing table, my measures don’t reflect the same value, but they will if a slicer is applied. Is there a way to do this without using slicers?

Comment: There is no such thing as "measures that calculate from another pivot table". Measures always calculate from the data model, and they do not depend on the filters applied to another pivot table. What you can do (I assume you are using Power Pivot) is to use the same slicers to control multiple pivot tables: https://excelchamps.com/pivot-table/link-slicer-to-multiple-pivot-tables/

Comment: That’s correct, I’m using Power Pivot. I have achieved this in excel using nested formula containing SUBTOTAL. Currently I have a slicer which is connected to both tables and it works fine, however I was aiming to do this programmatically as slicers aren’t very suitable for the amount of records that are contained in the table that I am wanting my summary to reflect